# jquery - how to get number from a string with mixture of letters and number

Tags: jquery, html

How do I use JQuery to get number from the drop down select?

```
<select aria-invalid="false" id="RatePercent" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select ratePercent" name="RatePercent">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="Floating-6.5%">Floating-6.5%</option>
    <option value="6 Months-5.65%">6 Months-5.65%</option>
    <option value="1 Year-5.85%">1 Year-5.85%</option>
    <option value="18 Months-5.99%">18 Months-5.99%</option>
    <option value="2 Years-6.19%">2 Years-6.19%</option>
    <option value="3 Years-6.85%">3 Years-6.85%</option>
    <option value="4 Years-7.19%">4 Years-7.19%</option>
    <option value="5 Years-7.40%">5 Years-7.40%</option>
</select>
```

If you choose 1 Year-5.85%, it returns '5.85', instead of '1 Year-5.85%'?

Comment: You could `split` on "-", grab the second element and `replace` the "%" with ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .prop() and the replace function:

```
$(selector).prop("value").replace(/.*\-([0-9\.]+).*/, "$1");
```

This pulls the full value from the property and returns just the number.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zR6FC/

Comment: I think he just wants to extract the numeric part from the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#RatePercent').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val != '') {
        val = parseFloat(val.split('-')[1]);
    }
    console.log(val);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aen22/)

Answer (score 0):

Use split here like:

```
 $('#RatePercent').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
 if (val != '') {
    val = parseFloat(val.split('-')[1].split('%')[0]);
 }
  alert("Required value= "+val);
});
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression:

```
$('#RatePercent').on('change', function() {
    var re = /(\d(?:\.\d*))%$/,
    matches = this.value.match(re);

    if (matches) {
        console.log(matches[1]);
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/kalomacu/1/watch?js,console,output)

Comment: That is kind of what I just did... :)

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih Sort of, but my expression matches what you want instead of what you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, use `$.data()`

```
<select aria-invalid="false" id="RatePercent" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select ratePercent" name="RatePercent">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="Floating-6.5%" data-number="6.5">Floating-6.5%</option>
    <option value="6 Months-5.65%" data-number="5.65">6 Months-5.65%</option>
</select>
```

to access:

```
$(this).data("number");
```